# How do I get one click to animate two separate divs with AngularJS and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have 2 divs, and they meet centered in the middle of the screen. They are both shown at the same time, initially. When I click the left button, the left div translates and scales to fill the screen, centered. However, the right div stays in its place, when it need to slide along with the left div towards the right till it's off screen, for a fluid motion. The same is true for the right button, except vice versa. When the right button is clicked, the right div translates and scales to fill the screen, centered. Again, the problem here is that the left div stays put, when it should smoothly animate with the right div the same way to the left until it is off-screen. Do not mind the messy code, as I have tried multiple things and have yet to clean it all up. Both slides should slide at the same time when a button is clicked, and the direction is dependent on which button was clicked.

Here are the CSS animations:

```
.side-left.ng-hide {
    display:block!important;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.side-right.ng-hide {
    display:block!important;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Here is the file:

```
        <div class="section side-left" ng-hide="slide1">
            <a ng-click="slide1=!slide1">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left pull-left"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="section side-right" ng-hide="slide2">
            <a ng-click="slide2=!slide2">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right pull-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you provide codepen?

Comment: I cannot, it is a private project, and information disclosure is limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [angular-flippy](https://github.com/zwacky/angular-flippy).

Answer (score 0):

i think u can use animation not transition
u may need left-in,left-out,right-in,right-out animations,
when change , set class side-in and other-side-out to the

```js
// Code goes here


var testApp = angular.module('test', []);

testApp.controller('t', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.options = ['separated', 'binded'];
    $scope.data = ['', ''];
    $scope.current = -1;


    $scope.goleft = function() {
      if ($scope.current < 0) {
        $scope.current = $scope.data.length - 1;
      } else {
        $scope.data[$scope.current] = 'left-out';
        $scope.current++;
        if ($scope.current > $scope.data.length - 1) {
          $scope.current = 0
        }
      }
      $scope.data[$scope.current] = 'right-in';

    };

    $scope.goright = function() {

      if ($scope.current < 0) {
        $scope.current = 0;
      } else {
        $scope.data[$scope.current] = 'right-out';
        $scope.current--;
        if ($scope.current < 0) {
          $scope.current = $scope.data.length - 1
        }
      }
      $scope.data[$scope.current] = 'left-in';
    };


  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular-animate.js"></script>

  <style>
    .box {
      width: 100%;
      background: green;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 120px;
      visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    }
    .left-in {
      -webkit-animation: leftin 0.5s linear;
      -webkit-transition: visibility 0s;
      visibility: visible;
    }
    .right-in {
      -webkit-animation: rightin 0.5s linear;
      -webkit-transition: visibility 0s;
      visibility: visible;
    }
    .left-out {
      -webkit-animation: leftout 0.5s linear;
    }
    .right-out {
      -webkit-animation: rightout 0.5s linear;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes leftin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-100%);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes rightin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(100%);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes leftout {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-100%);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes rightout {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(100%);
      }
    }
    .box.red {
      background: yellow;
    }
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="t">
    {{data}}
    <br>{{current}}
    <br>
    <a ng-click="goleft()">go left!!</a>
    <a ng-click="goright()">go right!!</a>
    <div class="box" ng-class="''+data[0]">left</div>
    <div class="box red" ng-class="''+data[1]">right</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Every time I've used -webkit-animation or its variations, it ever works. I have the proper script reference too.

Comment: Do you have any idea as to why my project does't work using this method?

Comment: what your project look like now? using animation should be fine